# Work done or not in this case?

Tags: energy, momentum, work, inertia

I have a very simple question. A motorboat directed upstream is seen to be at rest from the bank of a river. Is the engine doing any work? Is it right to say that since it is not causing any displacement, so it is not doing any work.

Answer (score 4):

It does do work: it's causing the water in the wake of the boat to move downstream faster than the rest of the current.  The engine is doing work on the water, rather than doing work on the boat.

Comment: Plus, the "correct" reference frame would be the water moving along the stream.

Comment: @Davidmh, that's certainly simpler, but the question does have a correct answer in all reference frames.

Comment: True, "correct" is actually a badly chosen word.